# How to remove/disable the print button from the DocumentViewer in code (when on its own thread)?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, print-preview, documentviewer

I am running the following code in a background thread as an STA apartment to provide a Print Preview in a document viewer:

```
 // Print Preview
        public static void PrintPreview(FixedDocument fixeddocument)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            using (Package p = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                Uri u = new Uri("pack://TemporaryPackageUri.xps");

                PackageStore.AddPackage(u, p);

                XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(p, CompressionOption.Maximum, u.AbsoluteUri);

                XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(doc);

                writer.Write(fixeddocument.DocumentPaginator);

                var previewWindow = new Window();
                var docViewer = new DocumentViewer();
                previewWindow.Content = docViewer;

    THIS FAILS --->   docViewer.CommandBindings.Remove(???Print Button???);

                FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                docViewer.Document = fixedDocumentSequence as IDocumentPaginatorSource;

                previewWindow.ShowDialog();

                PackageStore.RemovePackage(u);
                doc.Close();
            }
        }
```

All works well. However, since this is running in its own thread--not the main thread--the print dialogue on the Document Viewer crashes.

In code, how can I **remove** and/or **disable** the Print button from the DocumentViewer??  (I have read everything I could find in Google, and it all is in XAML, not very helpful).

Any help is much appreciated. TIA

Update#1: The only way I can see to do this, is to drop the Print Button from the control template and use a custom Document Viewer. A workable style is given at [Document Viewer Style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452.aspx#DocumentViewer%20ControlTemplate%20Example).

It still would be nice if I could simply remove the button from the system Document viewer?

Comment: You can use Dispatcher

Comment: @FCin How use Dispatcher? Any idea how to remove Print from DocumentViewer? Thanks. (The Print Preview works well from a separate thread, no need to use the Dispatcher).

Comment: You want to call `docViewer.CommandBindings.Remove()` from UI thread, right?

Comment: @Fcin Yes...or somthing along those lines...but what to remove? :)

Comment: @FCin --but I do wish to keep the other functions of that tool bar. (like zoom and multiple page views, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/how-can-i-find-wpf-controls-by-name-or-type/1759923#1759923) from this answer, you can alter the visibility of the PrintButton programmatically like this. Let's say I put the method in a class called `UIElementHelper`:

```
     var button = UIElementHelper.FindChild<Button>(docViewer, "PrintButton");
     button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```